# jQuery nested ul drop down menu

Tags: jquery

I have a simple ul menu [here](http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/nav/index1.html) with nested ul's

I want the nested menu to slide down when the link is clicked 
and slide up again on the second click. This is working.

I also need any other open nested menus to close when another link is clicked.
This isn't working.

I tried to use this to close any open nested menus before I open the nested menu I want
but this also closes the nested menu when a link in the nested menu is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav ul.children').slideUp();
    $('#nav li').click(function (e) {
        $('ul.children').slideUp();
        $('ul', this).slideToggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/nav/index2.html

How can I slideToggle the nested menus when it's parent is clicked and close any open nested menus when another link is clicked.

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="#">One</a>
     <ul class="children">
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One/One</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.bbc.com">One/Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One/Three</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Three</a>
     <ul class="children">
        <li><a href="#">Three/One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three/Two</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>  
 </ul>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#nav ul.children').slideUp();
   $('#nav li').click(function(e){
     //$('ul.children').slideUp();
     $('ul', this).slideToggle();
     e.stopPropagation();
   });
 });
```

**EDIT**

I have another major problem with my code, because I close the nested ul at the start with

```
$('#nav ul.children').slideUp();
```

When a link is clicked and the page reloads the all the menus are closed.
How can I keep the nested menu open when the page reloads.

Comment: Your links are dead, that's not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the action when a sub-item is clicked, use this:

```
$('#nav > li').click(function(e){ ...
```

the '>' character selects an li that is a *child* in contrast to any *descendent*

...so the `$('ul.children').slideUp();` will not occur when clicking on a link in the sub-bmenus.

Answer (score 0):

first of all hide all nested ul tags hidden using css style on page load to solve your second problem (pageload)

```
 li ul
 {
   display:none;
 }
```

put this script

```
 $("#nav li").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find("li ul:visible").slideUp(); //this helps to slideUp visible uls
    //then your code
 });
```